# Symfony FOSUserBundle doesn't translate

Tags: symfony, translation, fosuserbundle

I am learning Symfony 2. According to documentation I have added FOSUserBundle
and everything works fine besides the translation.
I have

```
 translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

in `config.yml` but form labels are not translated, even if I change above to `~`.
What should I do to have default translation values in the forms?

**EDIT**
Problem solved: just cleared the cache and translation appeared...